# Discord.py - discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to create a bot. All privileged gateway intents are set to true in the developer portal. I have seen other questions on Stack Overflow on this, but they all say to change the intents code to `intents = discord.Intents.all()` or add `intents.message_content = True` or to make sure all intents are selected in the portal. However, all of these I have done or tried.

This is my current code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", help_command = None, intents = intents)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True

token = "---"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Ready as {bot.user}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
      return

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Pong!")
bot.run(token)
```

The bot should recognize the ;ping command and respond with "Pong!" However, nothing happens. An error is not thrown, however before the `on_ready()` event is set and it prints "Ready as...", the console says:

`WARNING: discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.`

Comment: You changed the intents after you already assigned them to the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start, you placed `intents.message_content = True` and `intents.messages = True` after you defined `bot` You need to make sure these two lines go before you define bot. Also, make sure the actual toggles in the developer portal for your bot are switched on.[Here][1]

Here is the revised code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", help_command = None, intents = intents)


token = "---"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Ready as {bot.user}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
      return

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Pong!")
bot.run(token)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOB0Z.png
```